# Should it really be called "valence *sub*shell"?

Tags: atomic-physics, terminology, physical-chemistry, orbitals

[The Wikipedia article on electron shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell) states this, which I (a chemical layman) also always assumed:

> The electrons in the outermost occupied shell (or shells) determine the chemical properties of the atom; it is called the valence shell.

It appears this is wrong. What really appears to determine the chemical properties is the outermost occupied *sub*shell, ie. the things called 2s, 3p, etc. (Let's call this the "valence subshell" for now).

In particular, the noble gasses don't have a full valence shell at all (except helium and neon), but they do have a full valence subshell.

The same article also states that

> A nonmetal atom tends to attract additional valence electrons to attain a full valence shell.

By this logic, noble gasses other than helium should be reactive.

I suspect this isn't simply a screw-up on Wikipedia's part, since the term "valence shell" is popular, while even the term "subshell" itself is rarely used. "Valence subshell" does return google results, but extremely few.

So, what's going on here?

Comment: You say: "By this logic, noble gasses other than helium should be reactive." How many electrons needs, in your opinion, the Neon atom, to obtain a full valence shell? One electron? Two electrons? How many?

Comment: I think you are mostly hung up on semantics. The detailed reality of chemical bonds is far more complicated than what can be described with words like "valence shell" and it requires complex quantum mechanical calculations. Even the usual convention of introductory chemistry to treat the atomic bond problem as an extrapolation of the solutions of the single electron Schroedinger equation is essentially wrong in the general case. This oversimplification is necessary for purposes of teaching, because the real thing is far too complex to force on students early on.

Comment: @Sofia You're right, Neon is an exception too. Argon however, has 10 electrons left to fill its third shell: The 10 electrons in the 3d subshell.

Comment: @Sofia  No.  It just so happens that the first two noble gases Helium and Neon, have a full outter shell. But, the rest(argon, krypton xenon, radon oganesson) don't! Those 6 of the 8,  only have a full outter subshell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points.

> outermost occupied *sub*shell

generally everything that is in the outershell n highest (and sometimes electrons from lower subshells e.g. 3d in first row of transitions metals) has an impact on the chemistry and we can't generally say it is just the outer subshell.

> noble gases

in general chemical discussion 8 electrons is considered a 'full' shell - and as pointed out by Sofia this is the case for Neon. You are, of course, correct that outer valence shells beyond Neon can take more than 8 electrons.

In line with Curious One's comment the situation is much more complicated than the description that you have looked at, but what can we do? At some point things have to be simplified for chemistry - a reasonable insight is that most non-metals head towards 8 electrons in the outer shell, though many times this rule is broken.

You might want to look at the difference between Valence Bond theory and Molecular Orbital theory - this is an old debate in chemistry as to how to describe 'bonding' in molecules. Neither is perfect and each has its merits and I don't plan to support one or the other here.

Comment: Thanks, also especially for this: "head towards 8 electrons". I never saw this spelled out anywhere.

Comment: @John Glad that this was useful. The 8 electron rule is good particularly for first row elements like C, N, O and where electrons are 'shared' in 'covalent bonds' e.g. water H$_2$O or ions where metals like Na loose an electron to become Na$^+$ and have eight electrons in the outer shell or non-metals like Cl gain an electron to become Cl$^-$ and again have eight electrons in the outer shell.

Comment: Is there ever a case where the electrons taken on or passed away for covalent/ionic bonding at one time are from different subshells within the valence shell? If the answer to that was no, I'm really wondering why the focus isn't on the subshell only - or why "shell" is in fact not defined to mean subshell in the first place.

Comment: @John - Yes - take methane - CH$_4$ - C shares 4 electrons from the 4 hydrogen atoms, which each contribute one electron, plus the two 2s electrons and two 2p electrons from carbon. All these eight electrons are important for the bonding of the molecule. - there are many examples, which are similar to this.

Comment: But even if both s and p electrons are used for bonding, it's purely p-"slots" getting filled at the carbon side and purely s-electrons lost by the hydrogen.

Are there examples where s-"slots" and p-"slots" are both filled, or analogously s-electrons and p-electrons lost? I'm trying to establish if this "tendency to get whole" is really subshell rather than shell-based.

Comment: @John  - no in VB (valence bond) theory - there is sp$^3$ hybridization - and in MO (molecular orbital) theory bonding orbitals are formed between H1s and C 2P and H1s and C2s. - neither theory can cope without using the 2s.... Thinking about 'p' slots - there are 3 p orbitals and each can have 2 electrons by the pauli exclusion principle... so we need the S as well for the 8 electrons.... but again this is a simplification.

Comment: Order of subshells is different to order of shells.  Both go starting inwards,to outwards, following energy levels in ascending order, (if one is to speak of inwards and outwards).  When they speak of shells it's 1,2,3,4.5,6,7.  When speaking of subshells it's as per aufbau `1s, 2s, 2p, 3s, 3p, 4s, 3d, 4p, 5s, 4d, 5p, 6s, 4f, 5d, 6p, 7s, 5f, 6d, 7p`.   So it is outter most subshell that is full.  For Hydrogen 1s, for Helium 2p ,.. For Neon 3p. For Krypton 4p. that is full.  I can't comment re VB theory and MO theory but will check with somebody that knows.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer.** Valence Shell is a subset of subshells in the period the element is in. And for the particular subset of subshells, see the wikipedia article mentioned later.

**Longer answer**

I think valence shell is a funny term, 'cos subshells are more relevant than shells.

Order of subshells is different to order of shells. Both go starting inwards,to outwards, following energy levels in ascending order, (if one is to speak of inwards and outwards). When they speak of shells it's 1,2,3,4.5,6,7. When speaking of subshells it's as per aufbau 1s, 2s, 2p, 3s, 3p, 4s, 3d, 4p, 5s, 4d, 5p, 6s, 4f, 5d, 6p, 7s, 5f, 6d, 7p. So it is outter most subshell that is full. For Hydrogen 1s, for Helium 2p ,.. For Neon 3p. For Krypton 4p. that is full.

If it refers to outtermost aka highest energy subshell, then it's clearest to say valence subshell.  The term "valence subshell" has 3000 results on google. The term valence shell has 900,000 results.  So, "valence subshell" is a term used by some.

If it refers to shells by principal quantum number, not considering subshells, then if with that  model you go past element 20, then you get inner shells filling before outter ones.e.g.https://ptable.com/?lang=en#Properties  while calcium is 2,8,8,2.  Scandium is 2,8,9,2  e.g. part of the third shell (3d) , is between parts of the fourth shell   3p 4s 3d 4p. Valency is to do with electrons , and  if by valence shell they meant the outter shell in that model of shells disregarding subshells, then that wouldn't make sense. 'cos e.g. electrons in 3d are further out / higher energy, than those in 4s.

So as to what is meant by valence shell

According to wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_electron#Valence_shell

"The valence shell is the set of orbitals which are energetically accessible for accepting electrons to form chemical bonds."

And it gives a table, that specifies particular subshells

[image]

So there's basically rules regarding which subshells are meant re the term valence shell!  It's not all the subshells in a period. And it says "The orbitals involved can be in an inner electron shell and do not all correspond to the same electron shell or principal quantum number n in a given element, but they are all at similar energies"

It looks to me that all the subshells that are counted as part of the "valence shell", are within the period that the element is in. So the included subshells are a subset of the subshells within the period.

What constitutes a valence shell varies depending on which  category it is.That table has 4 categories "hydrogen or helium", "s and p", "d", "f".  Could look at it in 5 categories(though two have the same subshells).  The five categories- "Hydrogen or helium",  "s", or "p", or "d" of "f". For "Hydrogen or helium", it's just the s subshell. For s it's "s and p"(which is interesting).  For p it's "s and p".  For d it's "s,p,d".  For f it's "s,p,d,f".

So e.g. If the element is not hydrogen or helium, and is in the s or p block, then it's in that category called "s or p block{and not hydrogen or helium}".So if we take Radon for example (Element 86).  The period Radon is in, period 6.  The subshells in that period are `6s, 4f, 5d, 6p`. Radon is in the p block, so (as per that wikipedia table), of those subshells, only 6s and 6p apply. ns and np. So the valence shell has 8 electrons. They say the octet rule applies there.

Whereas if an element is in the d block, they still include a subset of subshells from the period the element is in, but since they include d, it's (n-1)d 'cos it's (n-1)d in the period. They include s,d,p for a d block element. `ns, (n−1)d, np`. And for the d block the valence shell is max 18 electrons. (s+d+p=2+10+6). For an f block element the subshells that make up the valence shell are s,p,d,f (32 electrons)